# How to scrape text from a <p> elements "id"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

i'm learning how to scrape, then I'm not really advanced. I wuold scrape from bloomberg the company description.
For instance from this page (https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=320105)

I would like to scrape

```
<p id="bDescTeaser" itemprop="description">Fiat Chrysler Automobiles N.V., ...</p>
```

My Script :

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html= 'https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp? 
privcapId=32010'
page = urlopen(html)
data = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
text = data.find('p',id="bDescTeaser",itemprop="  ")
print(text.get_text))
```

If I try to run the program I get,

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Is this a problem with my code or with this specific webapge?

Comment: Looks like a good time for debugging. Apparently your `text` object is empty (null), so some of preceding steps failed – and you'll have to discover which one (most probably the last one, i.e. `data.find()`), then guess why it fails.

Comment: would I also declare the "class"? I am not an expert of html, I don't know if the issue is related to the python code or my lack of knowledge of html....

Comment: Are you sure `itemprop="  "` is correct? Shouldn't it be `itemprop="description"`?

Comment: @GoogleUser: whatever could be your reason for removing the tag `python`!?

Comment: @keepitwiel, I tried but it doesn't work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your solution Bloomberg blocks your request. Because it thinks you are a bot.
You should use requests library and send user agent as header. You will get your expected output this way.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}
request = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=320105',headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')    
text = soup.find('p',id="bDescTeaser")
print(text.get_text())
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works!!! I supposed the problem was related to "bot control" . Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The get_text() must be given a open parenthesis. Change it from get_text) to get_text()